# Delphi - Pesquisar E-mail com IMAP4 (Código retorna verdadeiro para resultados falsos)

Tags: delphi, imap

Olá, bom dia. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que precisa acessar o e-mail, através do IMAP4, e pesquisar determinado termo no corpo do e-mail ou assunto. O problema é que tenho o código e ele retorna verdadeiro mesmo quando não encontra determinado termo no e-mail. Vou postar aqui e queria a ajuda de vocês.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  MsgObject: TIdMessage;
  SearchInfo: array of TIdIMAP4SearchRec;
begin
    SetLength(SearchInfo, 1);
    SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skUnseen;; // < Apenas msg não lidas
    SearchInfo[0].Text := 'CADASTRO REALIZADO'; //< Código a ser pesquisado


    if IMAPClient.SearchMailBox(SearchInfo) then
    begin
     ShowMessage('E-mail encontrado');     //< Ele retorna verdadeiro mesmo não encontrando a mensagem 
    end;
End;
```

Já estou logado e na caixa de entrada, INBOX. Não sei onde está o erro, pois o código não gera nenhum erro nem exception. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: veja se esta thread ajuda: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612968/how-to-search-for-a-specific-e-mail-message-in-imap-mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612968/how-to-search-for-a-specific-e-mail-message-in-imap-mailbox)

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!